# How to get the first and last occurrence on MSACCESS table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

it's my first question and i didn't find any answer to solve my problem, so i decided to open a new question.

I'm using a table "Access" that is imported from a excel file, so there is no primary key, like this:

`ID     |  Enter_date  |  Exit_date
   10     |  08/06/2015  |   08/06/2015
   11     |  08/06/2015  |   09/06/2015
   12     |  08/06/2015  |   09/06/2015
   10     |  18/06/2015  |   30/06/2015
   10     |  02/07/2015  |   03/07/2015
   11     |  12/06/2015  |   14/06/2015
   12     |  10/06/2015  |   14/06/2015
   12     |  02/07/2015  |   03/07/2015`

So, i'm trying to create a query to select the first register of the id on the table and the last register, ignoring intermediate registers, for a better explain i'm expecting this result:

`ID     |  Enter_date  |  Exit_date
   10     |  08/06/2015  |   08/06/2015
   10     |  02/07/2015  |   03/07/2015
   11     |  08/06/2015  |   09/06/2015
   11     |  12/06/2015  |   14/06/2015
   12     |  08/06/2015  |   09/06/2015
   12     |  02/07/2015  |   03/07/2015`

I started a code and i can get the first registers, but the problem is the last ones =/ because some ID's has 3 others 2 rows:

```sql
SELECT k.ID, k.Enter_date, k.Exit_date
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNo,
ID, Enter_date, Exit_date FROM Access)k
WHERE k.RowNo=1
```

Comment: Is the register represented by the enter date or exit date?

Comment: On "register" i mean when id appear on table. Each time the id appears is a register of this id. Each row is a register no matter the dates.

Comment: How does your query work?  MS Access doesn't support `row_number`.  If also requires `as` for a table alias.

Comment: I was testing on SQL Friddle using sql server sintax just looking for a good logic because is easier find codes for sql server, mysql or oracle on internet than MSAccess. But i need a logic for MS Access, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Enter_date & Exit_date do not overlap, the following should work. Warning, air code.
`SELECT ID, Min(Enter_date) as EnterDate, Max(Exit_date) as ExitDate FROM tblRegisters Group By ID 
UNION
SELECT ID, MAX(Enter_date) as ExitDate, Max(Exit_date) as ExitDate FROM tblRegisters Group By ID`

Comment: It worked!! thanks. With fews modifications like changing MAX(Enter_date) as ExitDate to MAX(Enter_date) as EnterDate per example ^^. Is there a way to include null values? Max function excludes nulls and maybe i will need to include then =/

Comment: The simplest way would be to substitute some obscure value. Something like MAX(Nz(Enter_date,#1/1/3000#). Other than that, the only thing I can think of would be to add another part to the UNION, which would give you additional rows in the case of nulls. SELECT ID, Min(Enter_date) as EnterDate, Max(Exit_date) as ExitDate FROM tblRegisters WHERE Exit_date IS NULL Group By ID

Comment: Thanks, the following code fit the objective:

 SELECT ID, Enter_date, Exit_date FROM SHEET1 WHERE Exit_date IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT ID, Min(Enter_date) as enterdate, Min(Exit_date) as exitdate FROM sheet1 Group By ID 
UNION 
SELECT ID, MAX(Enter_date) as enterdate, MAX(Exit_date) as exitdate FROM sheet1 Group By ID 

But i have some rows with some values (ID, Enter_date) duplicated and i have to remove using excel.